# Accessing an unordered_map

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

How can I improve the access time to this unordered map? If I instead allocate a 8 x 10 x 30 x 30 x 24000:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > > >
```

each access is about 0.0001 ms. Using an `unordered_map` implementation, each access is about 0.001 ms, 10x slower. What can I do to reduce the access time for this `unordered_map`? I'm doing a lot of insertions and modifications of existing entries.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "boost/functional/hash.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

struct Key {
  Key(int a, int b, int x, int y, int z) :
      a_(a), b_(b), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {
  }

  bool operator==(const Key& other) const {
    return (a_ == other.a_ &&
            b_ == other.b_ &&
            x_ == other.x_ &&
            y_ == other.y_ &&
            z_ == other.z_);
  }
  int a_, b_, x_, y_, z_;
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<Key> {
  typedef Key argument_type;
  typedef std::size_t result_type;

  result_type operator()(const Key& key) const {
    std::size_t val = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.a_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.b_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.x_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.y_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.z_);
    return val;
  }
};
} // namespace std.

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_z(1,24000);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> random_vote(0.0, 1.0);

  std::unordered_map<Key, float> votes;
  int total_accesses = 0;
  boost::posix_time::ptime start =
      boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
    int z = random_z(generator); // z in [1,24000]
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a) {
      for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; ++x) {
          for (int y = 0; y < 30; ++y) {
            float this_vote = random_vote(generator);
            Key key(a, b, x, y, z);
            if (this_vote > 0.8) {
              votes[key] += this_vote;  // This is what is slow.
              ++total_accesses;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if ((i + 1) % 1000 == 0) {
      boost::posix_time::ptime now =
          boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
      boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = now - start;
      printf("%d / %d : Milliseconds per access: %f\n",
             i + 1, 200000,
             static_cast<float>(diff.total_milliseconds()) / total_accesses);
    }
  }
}
```

I find it's amortized access time to be slow, and it takes a growing amount of memory (3.1GB after 4000 iterations of the main loop, 6.3GB after 8000 iterations, and 8.6GB after 12000 iterations):

```
1000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000548
2000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000653
3000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000682
4000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000834
5000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000874
6000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000926
7000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001107
8000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001143
9000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001187
10000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001234
11000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001285
12000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.001338
```

Here is the version using the vector of vectors instead:

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/functional/hash.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

struct Key {
  Key(int a, int b, int x, int y, int z) :
      a_(a), b_(b), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {
  }

  bool operator==(const Key& other) const {
    return (a_ == other.a_ &&
            b_ == other.b_ &&
            x_ == other.x_ &&
            y_ == other.y_ &&
            z_ == other.z_);
  }
  int a_, b_, x_, y_, z_;
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<Key> {
  typedef Key argument_type;
  typedef std::size_t result_type;

  result_type operator()(const Key& key) const {
    std::size_t val = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.a_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.b_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.x_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.y_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.z_);
    return val;
  }
};
} // namespace std.

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_z(1,24000);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<float> random_vote(0.0, 1.0);

  // This makes an 8 x 10 x 30 x 30 x 24000 vector of vectors... of vectors.
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > > > votes;
  for (size_t a = 0; a < 8; ++a) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > > a_grid;
    for (size_t b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
      std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float> > > b_grid;
      for (size_t y = 0; y < 30; ++y) {
        std::vector<std::vector<float> > y_grid;
        for (size_t x = 0; x < 30; ++x) {
          y_grid.push_back(std::vector<float>(24000, 0));
        }
        b_grid.push_back(y_grid);
      }
      a_grid.push_back(b_grid);
    }
    votes.push_back(a_grid);
  }

  int total_accesses = 0;
  boost::posix_time::ptime start =
      boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
    int z = random_z(generator); // z in [1,24000]
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a) {
      for (int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; ++x) {
          for (int y = 0; y < 30; ++y) {
            float this_vote = random_vote(generator);
            if (this_vote > 0.8) {
              votes[a][b][y][x][z] += this_vote;
              ++total_accesses;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if ((i + 1) % 1000 == 0) {
      boost::posix_time::ptime now =
          boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
      boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = now - start;
      printf("%d / %d : Milliseconds per access: %f\n",
             i + 1, 200000,
             static_cast<float>(diff.total_milliseconds()) / total_accesses);
    }
  }
}
```

It takes 7.2GB of memory and reports constant, low (relative to `unordered_map`) access time:

```
1000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000179
2000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000179
3000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000179
4000 / 200000 : Milliseconds per access: 0.000179
```

Comment: If your access pattern is the same as in provided example it's better to use single vector or even static array to store all data, and calculate index like this: `[z*8*10*30*30 + a*10*30*30 + b*30*30 + x*30 + y]`. It looks ugly, but it's fastest and straightest way in C++.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, it's somewhat hard to say, because you haven't given the code you are using with `vector`. Are you keeping it sorted and doing some kind of binary search to find the element, or is this just raw vector access times where you don't care about adding `this_vote` to a specific key? If so, of course raw `vector` access with something like `push_back` will be much faster, due to locality of reference, not requiring the computation of a hash function for each `Key`, and so on.

---

Secondly, this is where we grab our trusty profiler to see what exactly is taking up so much time. Compiling with `-O3` and running gives this:

> ```
> %   cumulative   self              self     total           
> time  seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name  
> 79.19     26.15    26.15      165   158.48   158.48  std::_Hashtable<Key, std::pair<Key const, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::equal_to<Key>, std::hash<Key>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::_M_rehash(unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> const&)
> ```

Which, if you squint hard enough at, becomes clear that `_M_rehash` is the culprit, taking almost 80% of the time. Unfortunately, I'm running this on GCC 4.7, which has a known bug that slows down `unordered_map` quite a lot: it's on the [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg368041.html) if you're interested. Further, `reserve` doesn't fix this problem. If you're using GCC 4.7, `unordered_map` will be slow.

The actual `insert` call is called 14311307 times, and accounts for only 0.64% of the time at 0.21s:

> ```
> 0.64     32.88     0.21 14311307     0.00     0.00  std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<Key const, float>, false, true> std::_Hashtable<Key, std::pair<Key const, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::equal_to<Key>, std::hash<Key>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, true, false, true>::_M_insert_bucket<std::pair<Key, float> >(std::pair<Key, float>&&, unsigned int, unsigned int)
> ```

Let's switch over to a regular `std::map`:

> ```
> 4.26     10.10     0.46 14311307     0.00     0.00  std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<Key const, float> > std::_Rb_tree<Key, std::pair<Key const, float>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::less<Key>, std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, float> > >::_M_insert_unique_<std::pair<Key const, float> >(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<Key const, float> >, std::pair<Key const, float>&&)
> ```

Now we have the same 14311307 calls to insert, which take up 4.26% of the time at 0.46s. However, there is not the huge overhead of having to rehash the map, hence this is actually quite a bit quicker.

The `std::map` code is exactly the same, except with a specialization of `std::less`:

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

namespace std
{
template <>
struct less<Key>
{
    bool operator()(const Key& k1, const Key& k2) const
    {
        return std::tie(k1.a_, k1.b_, k1.x_, k1.y_, k1.z_) <
               std::tie(k2.a_, k2.b_, k2.x_, k2.y_, k2.z_);
    }
};
}
```

and with `votes` being declared as:

```
std::map<Key, float> votes;
```

---

Since you're already using `boost`, why not try `boost::unordered_map` instead?

```
#include "boost/unordered_map.hpp"

std::size_t hash_value(const Key& key) 
{
    typedef Key argument_type;
    typedef std::size_t result_type;
    std::size_t val = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.a_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.b_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.x_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.y_);
    boost::hash_combine(val, key.z_);
    return val;
}

boost::unordered_map<Key, float, boost::hash<Key>> votes;
```

You can also save a bit of time by not constructing the `Key` if it isn't needed, and passing an `rvalue` instead of an `lvalue` reference:

```
float this_vote = random_vote(generator);
if (this_vote > 0.8) {
    votes[Key(a, b, x, y, z)] += this_vote; 
    ++total_accesses;
}
```

If you have an up to date version of `boost`, you might also try using `emplace`:

```
if (this_vote > 0.8) {
    auto val = votes.emplace(a, b, x, y, z);
    if(!val.second)
        *(val.first) += this_vote;
```

This may or may not be slower. I can't test it, but my gut feeling is it will be slower because `Key` is a thin object. If it contained more than a few integers, this would possibly be faster.

---

Basically, the final advice is to profile. Further, you're unlikely to get access times equivalent to a `vector` for anything else, as `vector` is guaranteed to be contiguous, hence will have good locality of reference and likely won't require as many dereferences as any other container.

Comment: @Sancho I modified it to perform less loops. I'm running on a machine with significantly less memory.